# Can we take transport equation of imaginary quantity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, complex-numbers, turbulence, viscosity

In the [RANS equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds-averaged_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) we approximate the nonlinear fluctuating terms to eddy viscosity times strain rate. Then by using turbulence models like [Spalart-Allmaras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spalart%E2%80%93Allmaras_turbulence_model) etc, we take the transport equation of eddy viscosity to solve for its value.

1. So my question is, can we take transport equation of any imaginary quantity (since eddy viscosity is a imaginary concept) are there any rules to define this property?
2. Also the no-slip condition says the eddy viscosity be zero on the wall or can it take any constant value (this does not mean accounting for round-off error while computation)?

Comment: Sure you can (computationally) advect any quantity, but does such a quantity as an imaginary one have physical meaning?

Comment: I suppose one could argue that if a growth/decay rate varied in time and/or space, then it could be described by some form of transport equation.  Also, I do not think your 2nd point is a question.  What were you asking?